# Зависимое свойство

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public class SMSViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private string phone;
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone;}
        set
        {
            if(phone!=value)
            {
                phone=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Phone");
            }
        }
    }

    private string textMessage;
    public string TextMessage
    {
        get { return textMessage;}
        set
        {
            if(textMessage!=value)
            {
                textMessage=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kак сделать свойство которое будет возвращать длинну (`TextMessage.Length`) при изменении `TextMessage` в рамках MVVM паттерна.

Сам смог додуматься только до следующего:

```
private int messageLength;
public int MessageLength
{
    get { return TextMessage.Length}
    set
    {
        if(messageLength!=value)
        {
            messageLength = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MessageLength");
        }
    }
}
```

и добавлением установки значения `MessageLength = value.Length;` в сеттер `TextMessage` после `OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage")`

UPD:

а если добавить например следующее свойство:

```
private int countMessages;
public int CountMessage
{
    get {return countMessages;}
    set
    {

    }
}
```

которое так же будет зависеть от `TextMessage` хотя можно его привязать и `MessageLength`, тогда в сеттере `MessageLength` будем устанавливать новое значение, нормально ли так делать?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну так в чем проблема? Мысль то правильная:

```
private string _textMessage;
public string TextMessage
{
    get { return _textMessage;}
    set
    {
        if(_textMessage!=value)
        {
            _textMessage=value;
            if(MessageLength != value.Length)
            {
                MessageLength = value.Length
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
        }            
    }
}

private int _messageLength;
public int MessageLength
{
    get { return _messageLength}
    set
    {
        if(_messageLength!=value)
        {
            _messageLength = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MessageLength");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на текущий момент у меня так и сделано. Но возникает вопрос а если добавится еще свойство зависимое от `TextMessage` продолжать писать в сеттер? у меня сомнения в правильности такого подхода, если таких свойств будет чуть больше...

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите

Comment: @Bald56rus, есть еще вариант, сделать свой OnPropertyChanged, в котором в качестве аргументов использовать нужные свойства

Answer (score 3):

В .Net есть готовая пара классов [PropertyChangedEventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager.aspx) и [CollectionChangedEventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.collectionchangedeventmanager.aspx). С их помощью можно задать обработчики, которые будут вызваны при изменении определенных свойств. В вашем случае:

```
public class SMSViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public SMSViewModel()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
            this, 
            (o, e) => 
            {
                TextLength = TextMessage.Length;
                CountMessage = TextMessage.Length;
            }, 
            "TextMessage");
    }

    private string phone;
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone;}
        set
        {
            if(phone!=value)
            {
                phone=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Phone");
            }
        }
    }

    private string textMessage;
    public string TextMessage
    {
        get { return textMessage;}
        set
        {
            if(textMessage!=value)
            {
                textMessage=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
            }
        }
    }

    private int countMessages;
    public int CountMessage
    {
        get {return countMessages;}
        set
        {
            countMessages=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("СountMessages");
        }
    }
}
```